# Dig through a list with list using a for function

Tags: python, list

In a function I am making, I have a `for x in range(y)` loop that will create a list with `x` list depth inside it.

For example at `x=1`, it will create `[[a,b],[a,b]]`
and at `x=2`, it will create `[[[a,b],[a,b]],[[a,b],[a,b]]]`

I want to be able to look at each element (each a and b), for example with x=1 do:

```
for small_list in list:
    for element in small_list:
        print(element)
```

but this is difficult for me to figure out because at each different x value, I would need to change the number of for statements. Is there a way to change the number of for statements for my list based on the changing number x, since x is linearly proportional to the number of for statements I need?

Comment: Use a recursive function. Basically you are looking for [Tree Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

Comment: Please add a desired input and output (not in words but with actual data). You question is confusing and it will be a lot easier to help if you show us what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single argument expression being re-called over and over to wrap your iterable:

```py
def wrap_iter(x):
    return [x]

# then a function to recursively call f
def nums(f, x, rep):
    while rep:
        x = f(x)
        rep-=1
    return x

a = [[1,2], [1,2]]

nums(wrap_iter, a, 1)
[[[1, 2], [1, 2]]]

nums(wrap_iter, a, 0)
[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to change the number of for statements...

No. Instead, you should create a recursive function, i.e. a function that calls itself again for a smaller problem until it hits some kind of "base case".

You seem to be looking for some kind of [Tree Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) function; something like this:

```
def print_tree(tree):
    if isinstance(tree, list):
        for x in tree:
            print_tree(x)  # calling itself for smaller problem
    else:
        print(tree)        # base case

print_tree([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to a recursive function, you can also traverse the structure keeping your own stack:

```
def traverse(tree):
    stack = [tree]
    while stack:
        current = stack.pop()
        if isinstance(current, list):
            stack.extend(current[::-1])
        else:
            yield current

print(*traverse([[1, 2], [3, 4]]))
# 1 2 3 4
print(*traverse([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]))
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```